# cannot display a list ?kam

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to dispaly a list on a button click.I have added a list box in .xaml file and want to add 10 text boxes in list.The following code shows errors.

```
      private void listbutton_C(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        String str = "thumb_";
        TextBox[] name = new TextBox[20];
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {

            if (i == 10)
            {
                strPath = str + "0" + i + ".jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                strPath = str + "00" + i + ".jpg";
            }

            name[i].Text = strPath;
            listBox1.Items.Add(name[i]);
        }


        ContentPanel2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

name[i].text=strpath    **show nullreferenceExceptions** .Can somebody explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to instantiate every textbox, you have only created the array.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        name[i] = new TextBox(); // insert this line
        if (i == 10)
        {
            strPath = str + "0" + i + ".jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            strPath = str + "00" + i + ".jpg";
        }

        name[i].Text = strPath;
        listBox1.Items.Add(name[i]);
    }
```